# sh/expect/sudo/screen all needed together in one command

Tags: bash, shell, expect, sudo, gnu-screen

What I need to have happen: PHP needs to launch an server app which has root permissions running in the background. All of this should be silent.

-Sudo is needed to allow php to perform an op that requires root permissions.

-Screen is required to allow the app to run outside the scope of the webpage which started the process.

-Expect is needed so that screen has a pts in which to run

-Sh is needed because whatever starts running needs to be backgrounded, presumably with the & operator. It would also need to pipe any output to /dev/null/since I don't want my PHP page returning anything. This is probably negotiable somehow if somebody can think of a better way to do the call in PHP (fork...?)

As an example, the script I tried to use was:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sh ( screen -t srcds /usr/local/srcds_l/startserv )& > /dev/null
exit 0
```

For reference I am trying to start a Counter-Strike Source server, and startserv is the name of the C code which handles launching the server and collecting its output. Can anybody correct my syntax for that snippet, or tell me why its the wrong thing to do?

Comment: You'll probably get some responses here, but serverfault.com might have people more experianced with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation was eventually solved by simply making the process daemonize itself using a fork and process group control and then just having PHP do a system call with a sudo in it.

I had another similar situation to eventually found

```
unbuffer -p
```

which uses screen internally, and does the kind of work that I was initially thinking of having screen expect and sh do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete solution for you, but you might want to look at nohup instead of screen. That eliminates the Expect need as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's a huge amount of overhead to communicate 1 bit of information ("start yourself now"). If you forget PHP then all the other subordinate requirements fall away.

If I was trying to do this, I'd probably write a perl script to listen on a TCP port for a "start" command and just fork off the process itself. This gets rid need for sh, expect, screen, and sudo.

Comment: PHP kinda has to be there since the whole thing needs to be called by a button in a webpage submitting an AJAX reqest.. I kinda doubt that it still more efficient to have a whole extra listen daemon just to hear a VERY occasional TCP request from PHP. Of course you're correct that there is probably a lot of unnecessary overhead there. I suppose a fork would eliminate the need for screen, wouldn't it.